# Addressing unsheathed cable: Replacing direct-wire under-cabinet lighting

Tags: electrical, lighting, cabinets

I am replacing my old halogen under-cabinet lighting with LED lighting. I removed the old lights, but the access plates on the new lights are in different places. The issue is that if I run the existing, unsheathed wires to the new access plates, there would be unsheathed wiring under the cabinet between the point where the sheathing was originally removed and the new access plates. There are two separate wirings for most lights since they are chained together.

**What solutions are there, short of opening up the walls and actually replacing the entire run of cable?** I considered cutting most of the unsheathed portion off and adding two low-profile junction boxes, if such things exist, but I think they'd be visible and not too attractive.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How about using plastic wire channel?

Comment: @DanielGriscom Is that similar to what is used in the first picture?

Comment: Yes; exactly right.

Comment: Or go 12/24VDC and moot the wire protection issue.

Comment: @Harper Using the existing Romex?

Comment: @BMS Sure if it works.  Very likely the current will still be within limits because LEDs are so much more efficienf.

Comment: Use a very shallow (1") Wiremold box with a blank cover.